# sql server: looping through a subquery and limting result in main query corresponding to evry row in subquery

Tags: sql-server, subquery

I am working on stackoverflow sqlquery portal. I want to have top 1000 tags with maximum post count. and for each tag need id of 60 post which have that tag as their tag. so i need to loop across all 100 tags and and get top 60 postid linked with them. sombody help please.

her's my sql statement.

```
SELECT Top 60 PostId,ok.Id
FROM PostTags as test
INNER JOIN (SELECT TOP 50
Id,Count
FROM Tags
ORDER BY Tags.Count DESC) as ok
ON ok.Id = test.TagId
```

but it returns only 60 posts but i need 60 for each top tag. Please tell me how to iterate through the subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
WITH CTEM AS
(
   SELECT TOP 100 T.ID
   FROM Tags T ORDER BY T.[COUNT] DESC
),
CTE as
(
SELECT P.POSTID,T.ID
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY T.ID ORDER BY P.POSTID DESC) AS RN
FROM PostTags P
        INNER JOIN CTEM T ON P.TAGID = T.ID
)

SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN<=60
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this: The query will fetch three objects out of sys.objects of each type

Post this to an empty query window, adapt to your needs...

```
WITH TypesToGroup AS
(
    SELECT DISTINCT type_desc FROM sys.objects 
)
select * 
from TypesToGroup
cross apply
(
    select top 3 x.*
    from sys.objects as x
    where x.type_desc=TypesToGroup.type_desc
) AS ThreeOfEach
```

Comment: It worked. Thanks [Shnugo](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5089204/shnugo)
I would have upvoted if had enough reputation.

Comment: @AkhilBatra, Hi, glad to read this. I pushed you a little ;-) Helped you to help me ;-)